# GroupFooter1 Size in ActiveReports

Tags: activereports

I have a group footer on a document which has a subreport.  The sub-report runs to more than a page.  Is there a limit to the size a subreport can be on a group footer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation to the size property of the subreport control but could you please email our support team to look into this? (https://www.grapecity.com/en/support/contact) That way we can get some more background on your question and see what report type you're using.